# Module build failed: Vue packages version mismatch

Tags: laravel, webpack

I use laravel 5.5, built-in webpack

```
Module build failed: Error:
Vue packages version mismatch:
- vue@2.5.2
- vue-template-compiler@2.4.4
This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.
```

what's wrong? there is my package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.5.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "bootbox": "^4.4.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "marked": "^0.3.6",
        "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12.5",
        "vue": "^2.5.2",
        "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
        "vue-localstorage": "^0.4.2",
        "vue-markdown": "^2.2.4",
        "vue-masked-input": "^0.5.2",
        "vue-simplemde": "^0.4.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
        "vue-upload-component": "^2.6.0-beta.3"
    }
}
```

even if I change "vue-template-compiler" to 2.5.2 - it not helps

Answer (score 8):

`npm update --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto` helps

Comment: I tried npm install and it did't work. I ran the above update command, it solved the problem for me.

Comment: This worked for me. It would be useful to describe exactly what this does.

Comment: Worked for me either..!!

Comment: Had installed less css and ran into the same issue, this command seem to have fixed it for me as well!

Answer (score 0):

re-install vue-loader or just delete node_modules folder and run

> npm install

Comment: node_modules deleted, after run `npm install`, not helps

Answer (score 0):

Using Laravel 5.4 / Webpack, I solved this with: 
1.) `npm install vue-loader`
2.) `npm install vue-template-compiler`

Answer (score 0):

Only runing `npm install` the problem was solved. Then, `npm run dev` and everything was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same version number:

```
"vue": "^2.5.2",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
```